# Regex to find matched string position with start() and end() using lookaround

Tags: python, regex

I have my string like **aaadaa** and want to search **aa** in it and return their respective index positions like **(0, 1)(1, 2)(4, 5)** with start() and end() functions.

```
import re
sequence = "aaadaa"
query = "aa"
r = re.compile(query)
print([[m.start(),m.end()] for m in r.finditer(sequence)])
```

It gives me the below output

```
[[0, 2], [4, 6]]
```

Obviously i can see from here it invlove the use of lookarounds here can someone give me the regular expresssion or the solution to find such positions.

Comment: `query = "(?=(aa))"` and then use `m.start(1)` and `m.end(1)`. [Demo](https://ideone.com/ExxEfI).

Comment: it gives this output [[0, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]] and it's not duplicate

Comment: As for the pattern, it is a dupe since what you need is *overlapping matches*. As for the code, you may subtract 1 from the `end(1)` - [`[m.start(1),m.end(1)-1]`](https://ideone.com/ExxEfI).

Comment: i got the ans but why we subtracting -1 to m.end(1). it starts with index 0 but still have 1+ for end. isn't strange??

Comment: Look, it is reasonable to say that `aa` end index in `aad` is 2 because there is the second `a` at Index 1. Index 1 is not the end, it still is in range of the match value. The match value occupies Index 0 and Index 1, and the char at Index 2 is already out of the matched value range - it is the end. I think this is the idea behind `.end()`